# What are the benefits of changing the temperature parameter in the chatgpt api?

Tags: gpt, chatbot

(Cross-posted from: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/39813/57463 after a week of no satisfactory answer)

**TLDR**:

What are the benefits of increasing the temperature in the chatGPT API ?

---

**Context** (can be skipped)

I believe that it is recommended to have a tiny bit of temperature with GPT 3 even for noncreative tasks like 0.2 or something (I am not entirely sure why).

Last I checked, and if I remember correctly, the examples from openai on their GitHub page use 0 temperature.

Is there any benefit in choosing a non-zero temperature for the chatgpt API when the query does not request a creative task? If so, are there some categories or examples?

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is a parameter that controls the range of possible values from one word (or a set of words) to another.

A higher temperature means considering words with a lower probability of building a phrase.

For instance, if you say:

"A racer drives a car" comes from a model with a low temperature, whereas "A monkey drives a car" comes from a model with a high temperature because there are fewer phrases learned by the model that connects "monkey" to "car."

In conclusion, the right temperature is not too dull nor too crazy.
Like any human conversation, there is a balance between too obvious and too original things: answers should always be logical but give some variability to inspire ideas or new replies.

Note: Top p and top k sampling are also important parameters.

See also:

https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate

Comment: Thank you. I did not have an example of where GPT 3 repeats itself in mind so thank you for sharing that link as it has an example of such a scenario. As ChatGPT is trained to reply in a human-like way, I imagine that even at 0 temperature it would not repeat itself. This is where I mostly feel uncomfortable concerning whether or not I should add some temperature. I am also interested in other examples that show the benefit of adding temperature. Also indeed, I imagine that adding some temperature can increase the feeling of spontaneity when casually chatting and not seeking any specific goal.